# Do seeds use cellular respiration when they are germinating?

Tags: cell-biology, cellular-respiration, seeds, germination

Do seeds use cellular respiration when they are germinating?

Comment: What have you found while searching on the internet on your own? PS: Consider asking yourself why seeds have a high fat content.

Comment: Seeds have preserved energy and nutrients in the form of cotyledons that are used for germination because they can't harvest their own energy until they grow leaves for photosynthesis. But I don't know whether they use cellular respiration, I'm guessing they do?

Comment: Google: germination oxygen consumption

Comment: @Timothy yeah, and how do you think the stored energy is utilised? How is it converted from its physical form of fats/carbs to help its growth?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those stored fats and sugars have to be burned to be utilized. Besides how ridiculous it would be to have a multicellular organism mature using only fermentation.

Comment: So seeds use their stored nutrients via cellular respiration? Thank you!

Comment: It would be helpful to provide citations to back your statement.